# How to force an update of a Single-page application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I work on a AngularJS Single-page application which once loaded (all the resources are fetched from the HTTP server) only accesses the REST backend to get/send data. The task is how to make sure users are always using the latest version of the frontend code (`.js`, `.css` and `.html` files) when the users never leave the page and never refresh the browser.

I think there are several options:

1. the frontend asks the HTTP server every N minutes what is the latest frontend code version
2. the backend includes the latest frontend code version in every response (e.g. an additional HTTP header) which is inspected by the frontend code
3. the backend returns a cookie with the latest frontend code version and checks if the version provided by the user is outdated
4. websocket connection between the browser and the backend (not an option for me)

Do you know other approaches?

Comment: yes, set version nos to files, also disable cache in headers

Comment: @vinayakj I do want to enable caching for static files, with just one exception for the `index.html` page, this is already addressed by the `grunt-cache-bust` plugin. The question is actually about a different use case.

Comment: well you said `"how to make sure users are always using the latest version of the frontend code"`

Comment: ok, my bad, thanks, added "when the users never leave the page and never refresh the browser."

Comment: you would of course need to notify the client in some way that it is changed and needs to be refreshed. There are many ways to do so, and which is best will depend on your situation.

Comment: can you please be more clear about  what do you mean by `frontend code`, do you mean the .js files or the REST responses or what

Comment: `.js`, `.html` and `.css` files, updated the answer

Comment: I would use the 2nd, since that would also increase the possibility that the user is trying to use the app and will be aware of the app refresh.

Comment: @KevinB can you briefly describe other options than the three provided?

Comment: websockets, passing the version number in a header with each request, cookies, pretty much anything that travels between the server and client with each request can be used. I prefer to use either websockets or headers, based on what's available in my current app.

Comment: @KevinB thanks, cookies was missing on my list, added.

Comment: @AdamSiemion How did you solve that finally. I found 5 years later I still can't find a satisfied solution. I also asked a question with new information https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/423068/options-to-notify-users-single-page-application-spa-static-resources-have-upda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use [html5 application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache), this way every time something changes, the website will update itself in the first visit, pretty handy and faster than ordinary cache.

Comment: "Deprecated
This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time."

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have used the 2nd approach in my Agnularjs SPA. What I did is

In my angularjs APP's .htaccess and my API Server's .htaccess I have added a header:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add appVersion "1.2"
</IfModule>
```

Now I will receive this header whenever I am getting anything from API server or frontend(js, html, css, images)

now in my index.html i have defined a variable something like

```
var frontendVersion = 1.2
```

I have a http Response interceptor that will look for each response and I have done something like this

```
myAPP.factory('httpRespInterceptor', function () {

    return {
        response: function (response) {
            var appVersion = response.headers('appVersion')
            if(appVersion == frontendVersion) {
                console.log('ok')
            } else if (appVersion != null) {
                location.reload();
            }

            return response;
        }
    };
});
```

I have added a null check because when i am loading a same view twice I am getting Empty Header Object and in my console i don't see any request that is being sent to the server..don't have a clue why this is happening if someone can shed a light it will be grateful :)

so whenever I will make a change in my code/update the application i will change my header appVersion to 1.3 and my index.html variable to var frontendVersion = 1.3

I hope this helps. And also Please let me know if there are best solutions other than this,

Thanks,